# symfony creating entities missing unique

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

Symfony is not marking the email field as unique. I can set it in validation.yml, but not a nice way. Anybody has an idea why symfony is not marking the email field as unique?

My commands that I run to create entities from existing db:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Frontend/AccountBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import FrontendAccountBundle annotation
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities FrontendAccountBundle
```

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=22 ;
```

In config/...../User.orm.xml:

```
<field name="email" type="string" column="email" length="255" nullable="false"/>
```

in Entity/User.php

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $email;
```

Comment: I think because an e-mail field not always must be unique. It depends on you.

Comment: Thanks, but in sql it is just varchar 255. It doesn't make sense, to enter this field unique too in User.php, because when I do the commands, it will be overwritten. Take a look at my command to the first answer.

Comment: Just use `uniqueConstraint` in order to describe needed field as unique. For more information, refer to this link: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#uniqueconstraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that the column has to hold unique values like this:

```
@ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", unique=true, length=255, nullable=false)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Yes, but Entity/User.php & User.php is created by the three commands. Why doesn't symfony create unique=true by these commands? Is something wrong with my sql-file?

Comment: Doctrine's conversion from databases is not always reliable, and it has to be this way because of the way various databases might implement unique constraints.  Remember symfony2 does a large amount of things for you, but it rarely does everything for you.

Comment: Okay, so it is not really nice right now. This is stupid because I am in development status and I often change the sql-file. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

@ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=25, unique=true)